# How to add data-attribute to li element for nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I correctly add data-attribute to li which is inside specific ul with class `.portfolio_nav`. When I'm using `getElementByTagName` it add data-attribute to all li elements on pages, but when I use xpath and specify that I need li inside specific class it doesn't add any class.

Here is my code:

```
function addDataAttr( $items, $args ) {
    $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($items);
    libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $find = $xpath->query('//ul[contains(@class, "nav_portfolio")]/li');
    //$find = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li'); -> working example

    foreach ($find as $item ) {
        $item->setAttribute('data-filter','office');
    }

    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'addDataAttr', 20, 2);
```

**Navigation:**

```
<nav class="portfolio-nav portfolio-nav-head hidden-xs"> 
      <div class="filter_div controls row"> 
       <ul class="nav_portfolio"> 
            <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter active"><a href="#" class="scrollIt">Office</a></li> 
           <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter"><a href="#" class="scrollIt">Bedroom</a></li>
      </ul>  
  </div> 
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you out. I think you need to first find ul with a specific class name then add data attribute.

```
    <?php
   function addDataAttr( $items, $args ) {
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($items);
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
$find = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul');//find tag name with ul first
foreach ($find as $item ) {
    //check if ul has class attribute first
    if($item->hasAttribute('class')){
        //get class name 
         $className = $item->getAttribute('class');
    //if more than one class name use php explode function otherwise check with class name 
    $classes = explode(' ',$className);
    if(in_array('nav_portfolio',$classes)){
        //if match than use foreach for child li and add attribute you want to addd
        foreach($item->childNodes as $cNode){
            $cNode->setAttribute('data-filter','office');
        }

        }
    }
}

return $dom->saveHTML();
}
  echo addDataAttr('<ul><li> </li> <li> </li> </ul><ul class ="nav_portfolio"><li> </li><li> </li></ul>',array()); 
   // or your hook
```

Comment: still doesn't add, and i figure out that it doesn't even print class of ul, but it print classes of li

Comment: can you post how your nav html look like.

Comment: `<nav class="portfolio-nav portfolio-nav-head hidden-xs">
 <div class="filter_div controls row">
  <ul class="nav_portfolio">
   
<li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter active"><a href="#" class="scrollIt">Office</a></li>
<li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 filter"><a href="#" class="scrollIt">Bedroom</a></li>

 </nav>`

Comment: posted nav in question

Comment: your html is not properly colsed(ul and div tag). I think you need to add  $items= preg_replace( '/>(\s|\n|\r)+</', '><', $items );  just before  $dom = new DOMDocument();  let me know if this work.

Comment: everything is properly closed, i just accidentally removed it, nope it didn't helped:( I solved the problem with js, just wondering why this not working with php